# H3 text pushing flexbox element too wide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a row of 3 elements that are using JS to display flex properties on hover.  It works, however the text in the H3 element nested inside each element have different lengths.  The lengths of this text is pushing the width out.  If I set them all to the same text they display correctly.

I am going to be using this code twice, so there will be two columns ultimately.   However, the second line will have entirely different text in each H3 element.

I would like for the boxes to be unaffected by the text.  Everything I try seems to not work.  Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<ul id="ul2">
    <section class="secLI">
        <a href="plan/plan.html" class="li4">
            <li>
                <h3>Plan an Event</h3> 
            </li>
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="secLI">
        <a href="bands/bands.html" class="li5">
            <li>
                <h3>Band Promo</h3>
            </li>
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="secLI">
        <a href="contact/contact.html" class="li6">
            <li>
                <h3>Contact</h3>
            </li>
        </a>
    </section>
</ul>
```

JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("ul section").hover(function(){
           $(this).addClass("wrapper-hovered");
            $(this).siblings("section").removeClass("wrapper-hovered")
        });

    });
</script>
```

CSS

```css
ul {
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

.wrapper-hovered {
    -webkit-flex: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the text to wrap?

Comment: No, the JS and CSS makes the hovered LI wider.  When the hover state moves to a different LI the first one goes back to the original size and the new one becomes wider.  Basically, except for padding and margin, the width of the UL is 100% and each LI takes up 33% until hovered over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can't place anything directly after `<ul>` apart from the `<li>` element.

- replace that ul with a wrap div and remove the li completely.
- place the flex properties on the sections. The un-hovered section is given `flex: 1` which is changed to `flex: 2` on hover to resize.
- use the CSS [`:hover` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) instead of using jQuery
- make it look pretty with a `transition` on hover. The [transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) is applied to the non hovered section

Provide the un-prefixed flex property for modern browsers *after* the prefixed version.

### Demo

```css
#wrap {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
#wrap section {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #cddc39;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
}
#wrap section:hover {
  -webkit-flex: 2;
  flex: 2;
  background: #e6ee9c
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <section class="secLI">
    <a href="plan/plan.html" class="li4">
      <h3>Plan an Event</h3> 
    </a>
  </section>
  <section class="secLI">
    <a href="bands/bands.html" class="li5">
      <h3>Band Promo</h3>
    </a>
  </section>
  <section class="secLI">
    <a href="contact/contact.html" class="li6">
      <h3>Contact</h3>
    </a>
  </section>
</div>
```